# How to made separate popups for each element in array using JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, popup

I have an array with products in it. Each product is a separate block (card) on the page which appears after user uses checkboxes on the same page. The product cards are buttons. What I need to do is that when user clicks on any product card it opens a popup which is linked to said card. Like if user clicks on 'product1 card' it opens 'product1 popup', 'product2 card' opens 'product2 popup' etc.

I'm new to JS so i would appreciate any help, thanks!

Here is how I tried to do it, but it doesn't work.

```js
// Creating an array and put an individual popup code as 'popupHtml'
function showProducts(selectedValues) {
  const resultsList = document.querySelector('.results__list');
  const products = [
    {
      id: 'giorgiocasa',
      name: 'Giorgiocasa',
      values: ['cont', 'high', 'mirgroup'],
      popupHtml: `<div class="popup__container">
         <button class="popup__close-button" type="button"></button> 
         <img src="./images/giorgiocasa2.png" class="popup__image" alt="giorgiocasa"> 
         <div class="popup__text"> 
          <p class="popup__title">Giorgiocasa</p> 
          <a class="popup__link" href="#">Официальный сайт</a> 
          <p class="popup__description">Представительство: <span>MIRGROUP</span></p> 
          <p class="popup__subtitle">Условия работы</p> 
          <p class="popup__description">Скидка: 50%
            <br>Предоплата: 50%
            <br>Сроки производства: 45 рабочих дней
          </p> 
        </div> 
      </div>`
    },
    {
      id: 'piermaria',
      name: 'Piermaria',
      values: ['classic', 'midHigh', 'mirgroup'],
      popupHtml: `<div class="popup__container">
         <button class="popup__close-button" type="button"></button> 
         <img src="./images/giorgiocasa2.png" class="popup__image" alt="giorgiocasa"> 
         <div class="popup__text"> 
          <p class="popup__title">Piermaria</p> 
          <a class="popup__link" href="#">Официальный сайт</a> 
          <p class="popup__description">Представительство: <span>MIRGROUP</span></p> 
          <p class="popup__subtitle">Условия работы</p> 
          <p class="popup__description">Скидка: 50+3%
            <br>Предоплата: 50%, заказ до 2000 евро - 100%
            <br>Сроки производства: 45 рабочих дней
          </p> 
        </div> 
      </div>`
    },
];
  let matchingProducts = [];
```

```js
// Creating and adding a product card or 'no results' to the page
if (selectedValues.length === 0) {
    const noResultsHtml = '<p class="results__text">НЕТ РЕЗУЛЬТАТОВ</p>';
    resultsList.innerHTML = noResultsHtml;
    return;
  }

  products.forEach(function(product) {
  let matchCount = 0;
  selectedValues.forEach(function(value) {
  if (product.values.includes(value)) {
  matchCount++;
  }
  });
  if (matchCount === selectedValues.length) {
  matchingProducts.push(product);
  }
  });
  
  resultsList.innerHTML = '';
  

  if (matchingProducts.length === 0) {
  const noResultsHtml = '<p class="results__text">НЕТ РЕЗУЛЬТАТОВ</p>';
  resultsList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', noResultsHtml);
  } else {
  let html = '';
  matchingProducts.forEach(function(product) {
  html += `<li>
              <button class="results__card" type="button" id="${product.id}"><span class="results__card-text">${product.name}</span></button>
            </li>`;
  });
  resultsList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  }
  }
```

```js
// results__card are all button tags
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.results__card');

// Trying to open a popup linked to the specific product card after click 
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const popupContent = button.dataset.popupHtml;
    
    const popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.classList.add('popup-container');
    popup.innerHTML = popupContent;

    const container = document.querySelector('.popup');
    container.appendChild(popup);
  });
});

const resultsCards = document.querySelectorAll('.results__card');

resultsCards.forEach(function(card) {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const productId = this.dataset.productId;
    const product = products.find(function(p) {
      return p.id === productId;
    });

// My popup opens with popup_opened class and closes with adding popup_closed class.
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    popup.innerHTML = product.popupHtml;
    popup.classList.remove('popup_closed');
    popup.classList.add('popup_opened');
  });
});
```

*edit *
also here is a js for reset and submit buttons

```js
let resetButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.parameters__resetButton');
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.popup__close-button');


resetButtons.forEach(function(resetButton) {
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let checkboxes = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
    });
  });
});

const searchButton = document.querySelector('.search-button');

searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let selectedCheckboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  let selectedValues = [];

  selectedCheckboxes.each(function() {
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  });

  console.log(selectedValues);

  const targetElement = document.querySelector('#results');

  targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

  showProducts(selectedValues);
});
```

And here is html for this (it's a bit raw and ugly, I will add all checkboxes to the js but it's easier for me to work with a big html at this stage):

```html
<body class="root">
  <div class="page">
    <header class="header">
      <p class="header__name">Центральная мебельная справочная</p>
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="parameters">
        <h1 class="parameters__title">ПАРАМЕТРЫ</h1>
        <div class="parameters__square"></div>
        <div class="parameters__small-square"></div>
        <form class="parameters__form">
          <fieldset class="parameters__field" id="styles">
            <label class="parameters__name">Стиль</label>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleClassic" name="style" value="classic">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleClassic"><span>Классика</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleNeoClassic" name="style" value="neoClassic">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleNeoClassic"><span>Неоклассика</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleArDeco" name="style" value="arDeco">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleArDeco"><span>Ар-деко</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleProv" name="style" value="prov">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleProv"><span>Прованс</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleMin" name="style" value="min">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleMin"><span>Минимализм</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleCont" name="style" value="cont">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleCont"><span>Современный</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleEco" name="style" value="eco">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleEco"><span>Эко</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleEclec" name="style" value="eclec">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleEclec"><span>Эклектика</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleArNuvo" name="style" value="arNuvo">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleArNuvo"><span>Ар-нуво</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="styleGlam" name="style" value="glam">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="styleGlam"><span>Гламур</span></label>
            </div>
            <button class="parameters__resetButton" type="button"></button>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="parameters__field" id="products">
            <label class="parameters__name">Продукция</label>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productSoft" name="product" value="soft">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productSoft"><span>Мягкая мебель</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productBed" name="product" value="bed">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productBed"><span>Спальня</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productLiving" name="product" value="living">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productLiving"><span>Гостинная</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productDining" name="product" value="dining">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productDining"><span>Столовая</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productChair" name="product" value="chair">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productChair"><span>Столы и стулья</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productBath" name="product" value="bath">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productBath"><span>Ванная</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productAccs" name="product" value="accs">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productAccs"><span>Аксессуары</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productSmallForms" name="product" value="smallForms">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productSmallForms"><span>Малые формы</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productTextile" name="product" value="textile">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productTextile"><span>Текстиль</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productLight" name="product" value="light">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productLight"><span>Свет</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="parameters__choice">
              <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="productOutdoor" name="product" value="outdoor">
              <label class="parameters__label" for="productOutdoor"><span>Уличная мебель</span></label>
            </div>
            <button class="parameters__resetButton" type="button"></button>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="parameters__multiple" id="prices">
            <fieldset class="parameters__field" id="pricesfield">
              <label class="parameters__name">Ценовой сегмент</label>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="priceLow" name="price" value="low">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="priceLow"><span>Низкий</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="priceMid" name="price" value="mid">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="priceMid"><span>Средний</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="priceMidHigh" name="price" value="midHigh">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="priceMidHigh"><span>Средне-высокий</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="priceHigh" name="price" value="high">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="priceHigh"><span>Высокий</span></label>
              </div>
              <button class="parameters__resetButton" type="button"></button>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="parameters__field" id="features">
              <label class="parameters__name">Особенности</label>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature1" name="feature" value="feature1">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature1"><span>Диван раскладной на каждый день</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature2" name="feature" value="feature2">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature2"><span>Стол раскладной компактный</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature3" name="feature" value="feature3">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature3"><span>Стол туалетный компактный</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature4" name="feature" value="feature4">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature4"><span>Стол письменный компактный</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature5" name="feature" value="feature5">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature5"><span>Кровать 200х200</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature6" name="feature" value="feature6">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature6"><span>Кровать с узкими царгами</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature7" name="feature" value="feature7">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature7"><span>Современная витрина</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="feature8" name="feature" value="feature8">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="feature8"><span>Стол на металл. основании</span></label>
              </div>
              <button class="parameters__resetButton" type="button"></button>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="parameters__field" id="repres">
              <label class="parameters__name">Представительство</label>
              <div class="parameters__choice">
                <input class="parameters__input" type="checkbox" id="represMir" name="represen" value="mirgroup">
                <label class="parameters__label" for="represMir"><span>MIRGROUP</span></label>
              </div>
              <button class="parameters__resetButton" type="button" id="represReset"></button>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="results" id="results">
        <ul class="results__list">

        </ul>
      </div>
      <button class="search-button" type="submit" id="search"></button>
      <div class="popup popup_closed">
        
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p class="footer__copyright">© 2023 Ivan Israel</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html and how you are calling your function(s).

Comment: This is usually done with [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @mykaf Added full JS code and html to the post!

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loja de Móveis</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Estilo</h1>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="classicStyle" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="classicStyle">Clássico</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="artDecoStyle" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="artDecoStyle">Art Deco</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="contemporaryStyle" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="contemporaryStyle">Contemporâneo</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Preço</h1>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="lowPrice" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="lowPrice">Baixo</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="midHighPrice" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="midHighPrice">Médio-alto</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="highPrice" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="highPrice">Alto</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Produtos</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Características</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Representante</h1>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mirgroupRepresentant" onclick="showProducts();">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="mirgroupRepresentant">MIRGROUP</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="products">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="" alt="" id="modalImage">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var products = [{name: "piermaria",
                             style: "classic",
                             price: "midHigh",
                             representant: "mirgroup",
                             image: "https://murilos.pythonanywhere.com/static/piermaria.png"},
                            {name: "giorgiocasa",
                             style: "contemporary",
                             price: "high",
                             representant: "mirgroup",
                             image: "https://murilos.pythonanywhere.com/static/giorgiocasa.png"}];
            var attributes = [{name: "style", values: ["classic", "artDeco", "contemporary"]},
                              {name: "price", values: ["low", "midHigh", "high"]},
                              {name: "representant", values: ["mirgroup"]}];
            function showProducts() {
                var selectedAttributes = [];
                attributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                    attribute.values.forEach(function(value) {
                        firstLetterUpperCase = attribute.name[0].toUpperCase();
                        rest = attribute.name.substring(1);
                        console.log(value + firstLetterUpperCase + rest);
                        if (document.getElementById(value + firstLetterUpperCase + rest).checked) {
                            selectedAttributes.push({name: attribute.name, value: value});
                        }
                    });
                });
                productsDiv = document.getElementById("products");
                while (productsDiv.firstChild) {
                    productsDiv.removeChild(productsDiv.lastChild);
                }
                products.forEach(function(product) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedAttributes.length; i++) {
                        if (product[selectedAttributes[i].name] == selectedAttributes[i].value) {
                            var card = document.createElement("button");
                            card.type = "button";
                            card.className = "btn btn-primary";
                            card.textContent = product.name;
                            card.dataset.bsToggle = "modal";
                            card.dataset.bsTarget = "#modal";
                            card.addEventListener("click", function() {
                                document.getElementById("modalLabel").textContent = product.name;
                                document.getElementById("modalImage").src = product.image;
                            });
                            document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)